# Is there any tool to backup/restore Google Datastore entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I've playing around with Google App Engine and Google Datastore for a while now and I am facing the need to take regular backups of my stuff up on the cloud.

Is there any sort of general purpose tool that allows you to download all your data from a specific instance of google-datastore and restore it to another one?

If so, please enlighten me, if not - someone should do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) that is described in the Google Appengine [Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine)

Comment: is that only for python? I am using Java

Comment: I see that you have accepted the answer... does it mean that it worked for Java as well? Its been nearly an year since this question was asked, still there is no prominent tool for Backup and Restore of GAE Datastore in Java. Am I missing something here?

Comment: still no tool for java available?

Answer (score 4):

There is an opensource application available that I developed called "GAE datastore backup utility." It allows you to backup and restore your GAE entities through a GUI. It keeps track of your applications and your application's entities. It's currently only for Windows and Python based GAE apps but it sounds like something you are looking for. I see that you are looking for a solution for Java based apps. I will look into supporting this language in the next release.

http://code.google.com/p/gae-datastore-backup-utility/

Answer (score 2):

Follow this tutorial for Exporting and Importing Entities: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities

Windows:

```
set BUCKET=YOUR_BUCKET_NAME[/NAMESPACE_PATH]
gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" gs://%BUCKET%
gcloud datastore import gs://%BUCKET%/[PATH]/[FILE].overall_export_metadata
```

Linux:

```
BUCKET="YOUR_BUCKET_NAME[/NAMESPACE_PATH]"
gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" gs://${BUCKET}
gcloud datastore import gs://${BUCKET}/[PATH]/[FILE].overall_export_metadata
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the following site:
http://aralbalkan.com/1837

It is about the backup and restore of the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/gae_backup_and_restore.html

Comment: The project of this link is not been actively maintained any more

Answer (score 1):

I describe bulkloader.py no-config dump/restore in [What's the best way to back up data on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965622/whats-the-best-way-to-back-up-data-on-google-app-engine/4616793#4616793)

Answer (score 1):

After years, this came out as a feature of the [Datastore Administration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) in the app-engine dashboard, still experimental but still good news!