# What's the best way to back up data on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup

Google itself provides two solutions.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

One of these is new and experimental and requires you to run a separate command (and separately enter your username and password) for each kind of data you want to back up.

The other requires you to twice write out information on the structure of all the kinds of your data, information that is already implicit in your models file.  (We've got 25 different kinds of data so I'm sensitive to this kind of stuff.  Plus it will mean future changes will have to be made in 3 places.)

Then there's Aral Balkan's solution (google for "gaebar"), but his code on Github hasn't been updated in about a year, and he's additionally telling people to do some modification to App Engine internals (which seems risky, since they change in every version).

I think I'm leaning towards Google's non-experimental solution, but they all seem pretty bad.

Comment: see this question for additional info --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245632/is-there-any-tool-to-backup-restore-google-datastore-entities

Answer (score 11):

Here is a more explicit description of [bulkloader.py](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) no-config backup and restore solution.  I do not know when [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2175) ([stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412642/bulkloader-key-ordering-issue-with-dump)) arises.

Dumping data from fooapp into a file called dump1.bin:

```
python2.5 /usr/local/google_appengine/bulkloader.py  \
  --dump --url http://fooapp.appspot.com/remote-api-url \
  --filename dump1.bin
```

You must have the [remote API enabled](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Setting_Up_remote_api).  The `remote-api-url` might be `_ah/remote_api` depending on your configuration.

Loading up data from dump1.bin to a local dev instance:

```
python2.5 /usr/local/google_appengine/bulkloader.py \
  --restore --url http://localhost:8080/remote-api-url \
  --filename dump1.bin --application fooapp
```

This assumes a UNIX-like system and that appengine is installed in /usr/local/google_appengine.

I don't know if it works with Java, but it might.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [AppRocket](http://code.google.com/p/approcket/) (an open-source replication engine that synchronizes Google App Engine datastore and MySQL database.) The project seems to be active.

Comment: Seems like this project is now 5yrs defunct and has moved to github.  A few other devs have made some more recent updates - up to 2012. https://github.com/k7d/approcket/network

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the --dump functionality? Yes, you have to download each kind separately, but that's going to be the case with any solution. If you just want backups, it fits your requirements exactly.

Comment: Why must I enter my username and password separately for each kind?

Comment: You don't need to - just use the cookie caching functionality, which should be enabled by default.

Comment: downloading each kind separately is no longer needed.